# I uninstalled a package but not all disk space was cleared. What do I do?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, disk-usage

So I went to install a LaTeX distribution using `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`, and hit yes without really looking at the size of the package. It told me it required 3,550MB, but when all was said and done by `/root` partition was 5.6GB smaller, so I went to uninstall it using `sudo apt-get purge tex*`.

After that, for some reason, my `/root` partition is still 1.8GB smaller than it was immediately before installing the package. What gives? What can I do to get that 1.8GB back?

Let me know if more info is needed!

Thanks :)

Comment: When you install a package it often needs more packages (dependencies) to be installed. When you uninstall the application it doesn't take the dependencies with it.

Comment: You may have to run `sudo updatedb` and then check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running

`sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: @TaylorDavison :D